# ¿ Como configurar una app B2B personalizada para que este disponible para un cliente.?

Tags: ios, xcode

Tengo una app desarrollada y la quiero distribuir por el sistema B2B privado de apple.

Los pasos que he seguido son los siguientes:

- Subir la app a iTunnes connect. ( Xcode - Product - Archive - Upload to App Store... )
- Con el ID de Apple con el que he subido la App entro en la cuenta de desarrollador de Apple
- Voy al apartado iTunes Connect y a "Go To iTunnes Connect", seguidamente al icono "Mi Apps" para ver todas las aplicaciones subidas
- En la última aplicación subida debajo del titulo aparece una etiqueta con la frase "iOS En preparación para..."
- Pincho al icono para acceder a la información de la aplicación. Luego a "precio y disponibilidad"
- Luego en "Programas de compras por Volumen" elijo "Disponible de forma privada como una app B2B personalizada" y aquí se introduce la ID de Apple del cliente autorizado para el Programa de compras por volumen
- Seguidamente pulso "Guardar"

¿ Como veo si lo que he hecho es correcto ? ¿ La App supongo que solo le aparecerá a ese cliente cuando se conecte a la App Store ?

Comment: estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo pero no me habilita la opcion para distribuir B2B. Podrías indicarme como obtuviste acceso a esa opcion? No veo en ningun lado para habilitarla y el centro de resolucion no me da respuesta.

Comment: Para el acceso a B2B  la cuenta no debe ser enterprise.

Comment: En la opción de 'Programa de compras por volumen', no me deja habilitar la opción de: Disponible de forma privada como una app B2B personalizada ¿que tengo que hacer? Actualmente tengo una licencia de desarrollador iOS (99€), ¿me hace falta otra licencia?

Comment: Debes tener algún problema con la cuenta. Estas usando la correcta? El B2B ademas solo esta disponible para algunos países. ¿ Puede que el navegador que usas crea que estas en otro país ?

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente enlace se explica los pormenores de cada una de las opciones disponibles para subir la app: [tipos de distribuciones](http://info.bravent.net/recursos-tecnicos/c%C3%B3mo-distribuir-aplicaciones-ios) ,y en este otro como proceder para distribuirla por el sistema B2B: [sistema B2B](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev275598f16).

Comment: En mi caso he sacado unos números de distribución para repartir y que el cliente se baje la aplicación mediante este numero. Pero no logro saber donde tiene el cliente que escribir este numero ? En el propio iTunes para descargar ? En caso que sea en este al ser una aplicación B2B privada no se ven en el iTunes. Por otra parte si el cliente inicia sesión con su ID B2B en la ventana de compras por volumen para empresas le sale la opción de descargar el programa de una lista privada pero suministrando otros números de descarga  que tampoco indica donde hay que introducirlos.